# Improper PWD result in PS1

Tags: bash, macos

This issue is specific to MAC OS.

This is the code in the bash profile. Just updating the current directory path in the prompt

```
function __get_current_dir() {
    pwd
}
export PS1="\u@\h:--$(__get_current_dir)--\W$ "
```

Below is the behavior observed.

```
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--~$ pwd
/Users/dummy
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--~$ cd Desktop/
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--Desktop$ pwd
/Users/dummy/Desktop
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--Desktop$ cd ../Documents/
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--Documents$ pwd
/Users/dummy/Documents
dummy@mac:--/Users/dummy--Documents$
```

The output seen while executing `pwd` in the terminal shows proper path, but the same `pwd` evaluated in `__get_current_dir` is stuck with the path loaded when the terminal was opened the first time. The same code works properly in the `ubuntu` system.

Is there any fix for this ? The function `__get_current_dir` has a bit more code in it and it's logic is specific to the current directory. Since the `pwd` is not working here, the result of that function is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__get_current_dir` is being evaluated *when you define `PS1`*. That means it's static. If you run `echo "$PS1"`, you'll see `\u@\h:--/Users/dummy--\W$`.

To fix it, either use single-quotes, or escape the dollar sign with a backslash:

```
PS1='\u@\h:--$(__get_current_dir)--\W$ '
PS1="\u@\h:--\$(__get_current_dir)--\W$ "
```

BTW, [there's no reason to export `PS1`](https://askubuntu.com/q/960551/301745).

Also BTW [this is not specific to Mac OS, or even to variables](https://askubuntu.com/a/965500/301745).

Comment: Got it. Just read through the difference between single and double quote in bash, [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).